# Amazon SES - Domain Verification Failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-ses

I want to verify my domain for SES, and I have included the TXT record that SES gives me.

However, I've tried it 2-3 times, and SES always reported a failure. I suspect that it's because of incorrect TXT value. When I try `dig _amazonses.domain.co txt`, it results in

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
_amazonses.domain.co.   300 IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:_amazonses.com a mx ~all"
```

From what I read, the TXT value should be the value that SES gives right?

I think the current TXT value is because my domain provider has 2 existing TXT records:

```
TXT <blank> v=spf1 include:_amazonses.com a mx ~all
TXT * v=spf1 include:_amazonses.com a mx ~all
```

Should I remove these records to make the verification work?

Also note that both my A records are pointing to my EC2 IP.

```
A <blank> 1.2.3.4
A * 1.2.3.4
```

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? Same issue here

Answer (score 2):

I have found 2 really nice article for which helped me to finally get verified all the records that I needed for my domains:

These are here:

**Amazon:**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-verification-problems.html#domain-verification-check-dns

You can check that your Amazon SES domain verification TXT record is published correctly to your DNS server by using the following procedure. This procedure uses the nslookup tool, which is available for Windows and Linux. On Linux, you can also use dig.

The commands in these instructions were executed on Windows 7, and the example domain we use is ses-example.com.

In this procedure, you first find the DNS servers that serve your domain, and then query those servers to view the TXT records. You query the DNS servers that serve your domain because those servers contain the most up-to-date information for your domain, which can take time to propagate to other DNS servers.

To verify that your domain verification TXT record is published to your DNS server

```
Find the name servers for your domain by taking the following steps.

    Go to the command line. To get to the command line on Windows 7, choose Start and then type cmd. On Linux-based operating systems, open a terminal window.

    At the command prompt, type the following, where <domain> is your domain. This will list all of the name servers that serve your domain.

    nslookup -type=NS <domain>

    If your domain was ses-example.com, this command would look like:

    nslookup -type=NS ses-example.com

    The command's output will list the name servers that serve your domain. You will query one of these servers in the next step.

Verify that the TXT record is correctly published by taking the following steps.

    At the command prompt, type the following, where <domain> is your domain, and <name server> is one of the name servers you found in step 1.

    nslookup -type=TXT  _amazonses.<domain> <name server>

    In our ses-example.com example, if a name server that we found in step 1 was called ns1.name-server.net, we would type the following:

    nslookup -type=TXT  _amazonses.ses-example.com ns1.name-server.net

    In the output of the command, verify that the string that follows text = matches the TXT value you see when you choose the domain in the Identities list of the Amazon SES console.

    In our example, we are looking for a TXT record under _amazonses.ses-example.com with a value of fmxqxT/icOYx4aA/bEUrDPMeax9/s3frblS+niixmqk=. If the record is correctly published, we would expect the command to have the following output:

    _amazonses.ses-example.com text = "fmxqxT/icOYx4aA/bEUrDPMeax9/s3frblS+niixmqk="
```

**GoDaddy:**

https://www.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Domains/TXT-record-not-found/m-p/129225/highlight/true#M25042

I had this same issue. I transferred my domain from a different host. After the transfer my Amazon SES domain verification (the TXT record) and the DKIM records (CNAME) were no longer verified - even after entering them exactly as I had from the previous DNS host into the GoDaddy DNS area.

When I performed a DNS check in a command-line tool (Mac Terminal or Windows cmd) using the following code:

nslookup -type=TXT _amazonses.yourdomain.com yournameserver.com

I received the following result:

** server can't find _amazonses.yourdomain.com: NXDOMAIN

As I discovered (and as others have mentioned) this is because GoDaddy appends your domain to the end of the TXT Name entry. So if you enter your TXT Name as:

_amazonses.yourdomain.com

It will actually be recorded as:

_amazonses.yourdomain.com.yourdomain.com

(this means Amazon SES can't find the record - because they're searching for the _amazonses.yourdomain.com - hence it cannot be verified)

You can verify this by checking for the double-domain record by doing an NSLOOKUP. For your TXT record:

nslookup -type=TXT _amazonses.yourdomain.com.yourdomain.com yournameserver.com

Be sure to replace yournameserver.com with your actual nameserver. Find your name server:

nslookup -type=NS yourdomain.com

If your domain name has been repeated, this should return something like:

Server: yournameserver.com
Address: 12.12.12.12#53 (the IP address)

_amazonses.yourdomain.com.yourdomain.com text = "your_text_code_will_appear_here"

And to search for the DKIM:

host -t CNAME replace_this_with_your_DKIM_value._domainkey.yourdomain.com.yourdomain.com

Other forums suggest placing a period '.' at the end of your domain to prevent GoDaddy from automatically adding your domain again, but I have found this did not work with GoDaddy.

Instead, you must just remove your domain from the TXT Name and the CNAME Name. Instead of what Amazon SES Management Console suggests:
TXT Name*: _amazonses.yourdomain.com

Enter:
TXT Name*: _amazonses

The same applies for the DKIM CNAME entries. Instead of:
Name: big_long_code_here._domainkey.yourdomain.com

Enter this instead:
Name: big_long_code_here._domainkey

The values remain unchanged. I've seen some forum stating you must enter your values encased within double-quotes (" "). But I did not do this and it worked out fine - I do however have my gmail SPF record TXT value encased within double quotes ¯_(ツ)_/¯.

Wait a while for these to propagate, then check again with an NSLOOKUP (this time not repeating your domain twice):

For TXT record:

nslookup -type=TXT _amazonses.yourdomain.com yournameserver.com

For a specific CNAME (DKIM) record:

host -t CNAME replace_this_with_your_DKIM_value._domainkey.yourdomain.com

(replacing the DKIM code for each of the three records you want to check).

Or, use an online DNS checking tool (like https://dnschecker.org) to see if your changes are beginning to propagate worldwide (perform a TXT search entering _amazonses.yourdomain.com into the text input / or perform the DKIM search by entering

replace_this_with_your_DKIM_value._domainkey.yourdomain.com). If they are, it should be a matter of time for Amazon SES to verify your TXT and DKIM entries.

This worked for me, hope it helps - I've tried to explain it very simply for people like me (those who don't really know what they're doing and are learning as they go).
Cheers.

(p.s. Amazon 'paid' Support were not able to provide me with this information (I guess each DNS host is slightly different) I had to do it through trial-and-error).

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SES domain verification might be stuck in "pending verification" or in the "failed" verification status for one or more of the following reasons:

- The TXT record contains additional characters or is missing characters.
- Your DNS provider automatically adds the apex domain to the end of DNS records.
- The TXT record hasn't been added to the delegated name servers.

After you confirm that your records don't have any of these issues, then you can retry the domain verification on Amazon SES.

Check if the TXT record contains additional characters or is missing characters.
Test your TXT record using a DNS tool such as dig or nslookup. On macOS or a Linux operating system, run the dig command:

Note: Replace _amazonses.example.com with your TXT record name in Amazon SES.

```
$ dig TXT _amazonses.example.com +short
```

On the Windows operating system, run the nslookup command.

Read the complete Amazon article at Amazon SES domain verification might be stuck in "pending verification" or in the "failed" verification status for one or more of the following reasons:

- The TXT record contains additional characters or is missing characters.
- Your DNS provider automatically adds the apex domain to the end of DNS records.
- The TXT record hasn't been added to the delegated name servers.

After you confirm that your records don't have any of these issues, then you can retry the domain verification on Amazon SES.

Check if the TXT record contains additional characters or is missing characters.
Test your TXT record using a DNS tool such as dig or nslookup. On macOS or a Linux operating system, run the dig command:

*Note: Replace _amazonses.example.com with your TXT record name in Amazon SES.*

$ dig TXT _amazonses.example.com +short

On the Windows operating system, use  the nslookup command.

From my experience, check if your DNS provider automatically adds the apex domain to the end of DNS records. Simply `dig` without your domain name and eventually your TXT record.

Read more at [https://aws.amazon.com/it/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-domain-stuck-pending-verification/#:~:text=Short%20description,more%20of%20the%20following%20reasons%3A&text=Your%20DNS%20provider%20automatically%20adds,to%20the%20delegated%20name%20servers](https://aws.amazon.com/it/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-domain-stuck-pending-verification/#:%7E:text=Short%20description,more%20of%20the%20following%20reasons%3A&text=Your%20DNS%20provider%20automatically%20adds,to%20the%20delegated%20name%20servers).

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to identify where you have to make that entry. If you bought the domain in `GoDaddy` but hosting is in `1and1` and you gave `nameserver` of `1and1` eg, then you will have to add those details in `1and1` DNS and not `Godaddy`.

If you have bought the domain in `GoDaddy` and hosting in `1and1` but have given `A` record redirect to `1and1` from `GoDaddy` and not `nameserver` then you have to add in `GoDaddy`.

In most cases adding SES related settings in DNS is straightforward. Just add TXT name and value as given by SES. Even for DKIM settings.

But that's not the case with all servers.

Given SES String:

```
_amazonses.yourdomain.com   Pe82YD6rnCI0AXMHIZv8v0h/thYRZk97YCuQUA=
```

You have to enter in GoDaddy DNS setting TXT record only the following:

```
_amazonses    Pe82YD6rnCI0AXMHIZv8v0h/thYRZk97YCuQUA=
```

In 1and1 or VPSLink etc you have to enter the full text provided. Only in GoDaddy its different. It adds the domain name itself.

Answer (score -2):

To verify a domain you need to not have a SPF but a custom TXT record that Amazon provides. Check the documentation at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/verify-domains.html